# Sencha Touch Draggable Panel issue on IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, sencha-touch, panel, draggable

I have a panel that I would like to be able to drag and drop. To make the panel draggable, I am using 'draggable' property of the panel as mentioned in the documentation. However I am seeing different behaviour of the panel in different browser because of this property.

Please refer to the sample code below.

```
Ext.define('MyScroll.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.dataview.List'
],
config: {
    layout: 'hbox',
    id: 'main',
    height: '100%',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'panel1',
            html: 'Panel-1',
            style: 'background-color: blue;',
            width: '50%',
            height: '50%',
            draggable: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'panel2',
            html: 'Panel-2',
            style: 'background-color: green;',
            width: '50%',
            height: '50%',
            draggable: true
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Sample code has 2 panels created side by side and 'draggable' property is set to 'true'. When running the application in Chrome, I am able to see both of the panels correctly and I can drag and drop them successfully.

But when I try to run the application on IE10 (64-bit Desktop, Win-7), panels are overlapping each other in one location, which is an unexpected behaviour of the draggable panel. You have to drag the top panel out to see the underlying panel.

I do see the panels are draggable on IE10 but I would like to understand why the panels are not placed properly on IE10.

On the other hand, if you set 'draggable: false', panels starts to appear properly on IE10 but they are not draggable.

Help and suggestions are appreciated!

Note: I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.0.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heard back from Sencha Touch team. This is a bug in their framework. They are hoping to resolve it in future releases.